# How do I turn off admob testing

Tags: android, admob

I have been working with admob for the last few days and can not figure out how to turn off admob testing mode. I tried the settings in the website but i still get test ads and they flat out wont run on my phone. Log cat keeps telling me to add my phone as a testing device. Well I'm through testing, I just want to get things up and running live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can turn off the testing mode.

1. If you are creating Ad's using XML, you will have something in your XML's that looks like this: `ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, THE_DEVICE_ID"`
2. If you are creating Ad's using JAVA, you might have something that looks like this:

   AdRequest.setTestDevices( new String[] {
      AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR,
      "THE_DEVICE_ID",  // My Test Device ID
   } );
3. If none of the above work (for whatever reason), you can always log in to your AdMob account, go into "Sites And Apps", hover your mouse pointer over the App in question and click on "Manage Setting". Then, click on the "App Setting" tab and you will see a "Test Mode" option. In that, select the "Disable test mode for all requests" option and hit "Save Settings" at the bottom.

**NOTE:** I do not personally create my Ads using Java, so you will have to probe that a bit

**A SIDE NOTE:** I personally always rely on the 3rd option. Saves me the effort of going through literally about 65 odd XML's and removing my test device ID's.

Comment: I'll give this a shot, see where it takes me.

Comment: I took out all of the testing things and its still bugging me about adding it to the list.

Comment: @CodeMonkeyAlx: Adding what to which list?

Comment: If you're running your app on a device that is NOT in test mode, the SDK will continue to log how you can get test ads on your device. It's feature, not a bug.

Comment: @SiddharthLele Its bugging my to add my phone to the test list and I do and it still does not come up with anything.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag: Thanks for the correction. Appreciated. :-)

Comment: @CodeMonkeyAlx: _Eric_ has commented addressing that _problem_ stating that the logs will continue to ask you to enable test ads. If your intention is to disable all test ads, any one of the solutions mentioned above will do it for you.

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag Thank you! - Sorry I missed the post! and Siddharth Lele Thanks for pointing that out! I cant say this fixed anything on my end but I could just be acting the Dum dum in this case.