# How to disable the test ads in admob to get live ads in IOS application

Tags: ios, admob, testflight

We are using admob for to post our own ads in IOS app.

We created an admob account and created a campaign ad. And implemented in IOS app. Still i get test ad only in testflight also.

I searched for this and get the below link

[How do I turn off admob testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13198660/how-do-i-turn-off-admob-testing)

As per this directions i was not able to find path

Sites And `Apps ->Manage Setting->App Setting->Test Mode->Disable` test mode for all requests

Please suggest me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `testDevices`. For example:

```
let request = GADRequest()
// request.testDevices = ["2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b"]
```

From [Targeting - Test ads](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/targeting):

> Be sure to remove the code that sets these test device IDs before you
>   release your app.